# How can I edit the text in listview builder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list of items that is stored in a list, I display it through the `listview.builder` and now I need to allow user to edit that text, how can I do that
I tried using TextField, it changes the text but I also need to update that text in the list.

```
List shoppingList = [];
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: shoppingList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ShoppingListItemTile(
              addText: () {
                shoppingList[index] = '';
              },
              text: shoppingList[index],
              removeList: () {
                shoppingList.removeAt(index);
                setState(() {});
              });
        },
      )

class ShoppingListItemTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback removeList;
  final VoidCallback addText;
  const ShoppingListItemTile(
      {Key? key,
      required this.text,
      required this.removeList,
      required this.addText})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isEditable = false;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24, top: 16),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(text,
                  style: AppTextStyle.latoMedium(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 17,
                      color: AppColorPallet.zop_location_text)),
              InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    removeList();
                  },
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(AppIcons.close))
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
            child: Divider(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: to show changes on UI we use setState((){}) or streambuilder methods. If your list is changing continuously better to use streambuilder else setstate.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```dart
return ShoppingListItemTile(
  addText: () {
    shoppingList[index] = '';
    setState(() {}); //check here
  },
  text: shoppingList[index],
  removeList: () {
    shoppingList.removeAt(index);
    setState(() {});
  },
);
```